# Im getting an Object Variable or With Block variable not set error when copying ranges from one sheet to another using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to copy ranges from my WeeklyDiet sheet to my DietStats sheet.

In cell A1 of WeeklyDiet I enter the number of the week as follows e.g Wk1,Wk2 etc.

I want to paste the data for the week in A1 to whatever row in DietStats.Range(B4:B55) that contains its equivalent weeknumber e.g If Wk2 is in A1 I want the data to be pasted in whatever row contains Wk2 in Range(B4:B55) of the DietStats sheet.

**Im getting an Object Variable or With Block variable not set error message.**

```
Sub SaveDietMacrosForWeek()

                    Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
                    Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
                    Dim NR As Long

                    Set Ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("WeeklyDiet")
                    Set Ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DietStats")

                    Dim Week As String
                    Week = Ws1.Range("A1")
                    NR = Ws2.Range("B4:B55").Find(Week).Row

                        Ws1.Range("E75:I75").Copy
                        Ws2.Range("K" & NR).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

                        Ws1.Range("L75:P75").Copy
                        Ws2.Range("R" & NR).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

                        Ws1.Range("S75:W75").Copy
                        Ws2.Range("Y" & NR).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

                        Ws1.Range("Z75:AD75").Copy
                        Ws2.Range("AF" & NR).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

                        Ws1.Range("AG75:AK75").Copy
                        Ws2.Range("AM" & NR).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

                        Ws1.Range("AN75:AR75").Copy
                        Ws2.Range("AT" & NR).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

                        Ws1.Range("AU75:AY75").Copy
                        Ws2.Range("BA" & NR).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

                    ActiveWorkbook.Save

                    End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you said where you get the error.

Comment: will do. i forgot that.NR = Ws2.Range("B4:B55").Find(Week).Row

Comment: Most likely, `.Find(Week)` did not find the week.

Comment: What @A.S.H said.

Comment: whats that got to do with a block varaible not set

Comment: @frustrationmultiplied Because when the week is not found, `Ws2.Range("B4:B55").Find(Week)` returns `Nothing`. Attempting to use a `Nothing` range results in this error message. You should add a check for the result of `Find` before proceeding.

Comment: How do i correct it. Wk1 -Wk52 are in the range B4:B55. Have you any idea why it would not find the desired week

Comment: You should specify at least some of Find's parameters as they may not be what you expect them to be.

Comment: Thanks, how do i do that

Comment: See suggestion below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Applicatiopn.Match` on the whole of column B to get the row number. By passing the return to a variant you will either get the true row number or an error value.

```
Sub SaveDietMacrosForWeek()

    Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim NR As Variant

    Set Ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("WeeklyDiet")
    Set Ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DietStats")

    Dim Week As String
    Week = Ws1.Range("A1")

    NR = Application.Match(Week, Ws2.Range("B:B"), 0)

    If Not IsError(NR) Then

        Ws2.Range("K" & NR).Resize(1, 5) = Ws1.Range("E75:I75").Value
        Ws2.Range("R" & NR).Resize(1, 5) = Ws1.Range("L75:P75").Value
        Ws2.Range("Y" & NR).Resize(1, 5) = Ws1.Range("S75:W75").Value
        Ws2.Range("AF" & NR).Resize(1, 5) = Ws1.Range("Z75:AD75").Value
        Ws2.Range("AM" & NR).Resize(1, 5) = Ws1.Range("AG75:AK75").Value
        Ws2.Range("AT" & NR).Resize(1, 5) = Ws1.Range("AN75:AR75").Value
        Ws2.Range("BA" & NR).Resize(1, 5) = Ws1.Range("AU75:AY75").Value

    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

I've used direct value transfer instead of your Copy, Paste Special, Values. Direct value transfer is more efficient but requires a target that is the same size as the source.

Comment: Did you mean to declare NR as Variant?

Comment: This worked perfectly. I dont understand why Resize was used though. Can you explain how Application.Match made the search work. Many thanks to you both for helping out

Comment: As mentioned in comments, the find command has many parameters which, if not explicitly specified, use the setting that was used last. It reproduces the worksheet's Find/Replace command where if you make one search case sensitive, the next search is case sensitive unless you change that setting. Match is a command that doesn't do everything that Find can do but is perfectly adequate for what you want. There are almost always several ways to do any particular task; I tend to use the simplest method that gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what Week is so may need some adjusting.

```
Sub SaveDietMacrosForWeek()

Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
Dim r As Range
Dim NR As Long
Dim Week As String

Set Ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("WeeklyDiet")
Set Ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DietStats")

Week = Ws1.Range("A1")
Set r = Ws2.Range("B4:B55").Find(What:=Week, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not r Is Nothing Then
    NR = r.Row
    'rest of code
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Ive tried the code but it doesnt work. I didnt alter it before trying it. Im not quite sure what you meant by 'rest of code in the code above. In the meantime Jeeped's code worked below. Thanks very much for taking the time to help out